# SQL: Associate a single type with multiple records of various other types

Tags: c#, sql, database, database-design

Designing a database with many tables and want to add a general `Note` table. I want a `Note` object to be able to attach to several other tables. So one `Note` can be associated with a particular `Contact`, maybe a `Job`, and also a few different `Equipment` objects. I'd like to be able to filter `Note` objects by the particular objects they are associated with.

Comment: and?... you will need a note_id and some link classes.  either one with a type or many - one for each type.

Comment: Have a 'Note' table with a primary key, then a NoteId column in each of the other tables with a relationship to the Note table. The fields in the 'Note' table will be a One to Many relationship.

Comment: @KevinDeVoe Won't this only allow me to attach only one note to each object though? I'd like to attach many notes to the same object and many objects to the same note.

Comment: Then just create a linking table. TableId, RowId, NoteId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's one way:

```
CREATE TABLE NoteTables
(
    TableID     INT NOT NULL Identity(1,1),
    TableName   SysName NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_NoteTables PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(TableID)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE TableNotes
(
    TableID     INT NOT NULL,
    RowID       INT NOT NULL,
    NoteID      INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_NoteAttachments PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(TableID, RowID, NoteID)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Notes
(
    NoteID      INT NOT NULL Identity(1,1),
    Note        NVARCHAR(MAX),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Notes PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(NoteID)
)
```

Note that I am assuming SQL Server and the use of IDENTITY columns here (if Oracle, you can use Sequences instead).

The `Notes` table contains all of the notes and gives them an ID to use as both a referemce and a primary key.

The `NoteTables` just list all of the tables that can have note attached to their rows.

`TableNotes` links the notes to the tables and rows that they are attached to.  Note that this design assumes that all of these tables have `INT` ID columns that can be used for unique referencing.

Answer (score 0):

It would take you two tables. Structure is as easy as the following.

Note table:

```
NotePK | tableFK | note
```

And a table that lists all your tables. 
Either you create one (then you have full control but need to maintain it) or you take the

```
sys.tables t
```

You read it out by `SELECT * FROM sys.tables t`

the column `object_id` would be your `tableFK` in the first table

You can store as many comments as you like. If you want to get the note simply query the note table and filter for your `tableFK`.